# How to Get C# Error List to Instantly Reflect Errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have been coding in C# for a while now, and I am wondering...

I used to do a lot of vb.net. My experience was that when there is an error somewhere in the entire solution, the Error List in VS will instantly reflect it. It is helpful to me, for example, when I write some code to call a few new functions in a new class that doesn't exist, Error List marks them. So I can go to and write this new class and fill in those new functions, knowing that I didn't miss anything by checking the Error List.... Things like that.

However, in C# the Error List doesn't instantly reflect most errors I made. (Only text editor highlights it, but not error list) Not until I hit Build. Even then, the Error List will only show first layer of errors, after I fix something and Build again, Error List will show more errors.

I have to say vb.net Error List is more helpful in that sense. Is it possible to get the C# Error List instantly reflect errors like the vb.net error list?

By the way, I also have Resharper, I am not sure that will help me route anything to Error List window, too.

Comment: You don't think being more accurate is important?

Comment: Mitch: My question is totally legit. It has a solution many c# programmers didn't know, too. You should check your arrogant before voting to close my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2010 options, see if the checkbox 'Show live semantic errors' is checked under Text Editor | C# | Advanced.  In my configuration, I get instant feedback in the error list when that setting is on.  If I toggle the checkbox off, the error list no longer reflects errors.

Comment: +1 it instantly reflects errors now! i think it is working :D –

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know: [No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET#Development_environment). This is just a difference between the C# and VB compilers integration with Visual Studio. You'll just have to get in the habit of hitting F6.

Comment: Haha Brad, it has nothing to do with compiler! Thank WarrenG. it is just hidden in adv settings! now I know, you should try it out! a bit verbose to see those errors, but that is what an error list supposed to do! Trust me, once you get used to it, you find it very helpful for cross referencing.